# How to perform an apex batch update on multiple fields for multiple Objects stored in map (Record list approx 10million)?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a custom setting which stores object and its associated fields which need to be updated.
I am planning to create a map to store the object name as key and the list of fields as values.

```
 Map<String, List<String>> objToLongTextFieldsMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
```

I need to iterate the keyset to object name and its associated field names and pass this to a custom function to build a query string and return this query to the executeBatch method.

Query generator function: `Utils_PullDataFromObject.generateQuery(strObjectName, objToLongTextFieldsMap.get(strObjectName));`

However, my concern is to ensure that the Querylocator only processes the sobject records which are not updated in every transaction (say if the batch size is 2000) and for the first transaction on the first iteration of Account object - I pass the records list to executeBatch, then on the second transaction - it must process only the next set of Account records in the iteration and when all Account records are processed, it must break the loop for object names iteration. So on the next transaction, it must repeat the same process for the next object name.

Answer (score 0):

How about no?

You won't be able to make a query in batch's start method that runs on multiple possibly unrelated objects at same time. SOQL doesn't have "union" keyword.

Keep it simple. Mark the batch as "implements Stateful". In start method pick one of keys, build the query. Do your thing. In finish method check if there's still something to process and fire off new batch. Search for "daisy chaining" batch jobs.